# Is Trash a safe storage for files?

Tags: macos, trash

Are files moved to Trash do stay there until it is explicitly manually emptied?

My maintenance script automatically moves certain files to Trash, and I'd like to be sure I can recover them if necessary.

Links to references are welcome.

Comment: Yes, unless you have a program set up to auto delete files from the trash they'll just stay there.

Comment: If you want to be sure of the ability to recover files then implement a proper backup solution, e.g Time Machine, not depend on something being in the Trash.

Comment: I save all my back-ups in the Trash and I have done this for years. Super secure, go on! - Joking apart, be warned that the next macOS (Sierra) does empty the Trash automatically when it decides it's a good idea. You can deactivate this behavior though

Comment: @Zozor Thank you for the information about Sierra. This is exactly what I was afraid of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - they stay there until the trash is emptied.  You can learn all about the trash [here](http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understanding-the-trash-can-in-os-x--mac-4007).